# Why cannot I get previous route or url in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I am trying to get the previous url address ("/employees") before navigating to this Details page, but although I have tried to examine all of the necessary parameters `Router`, `Location` or `ActivatedRoute`, I cannot see or grab any parameter that contains the previous url. Is it not possible to get it using these variables or etc?

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location
    ) {      
      this.router.events.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          console.log('router: ', router);
          console.log('event: ', event);      
          console.log('location: ', location);
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: In which component do you require this? Is it in app component or some other component?

Comment: DetailsComponent only. Thanks

Comment: So you would like to know the previous route in the `DetailsComponent` before navigating to the `DetailsComponent`?

Comment: The scenario is like that: I have a list page and there are details button for each record on that list. When navigating to details page I store some values of the list page and for some condition I need to delete these stored values. However, it depends on the previous url before navigating to Details page. For this reason I need to get the prevous url on the Details page.

Comment: Is there a smart way or should I make something as mentioned on https://jacobneterer.medium.com/accessing-the-previous-url-in-angular-32cf97bec3ce

Comment: So essentially you would like to use some info from the List Page's URL in the Details Page (like ID)?

Comment: Not actually, I just need the previous url before opening Details page. Normally I could pass some parameters .e.g. redirectUrl from list page via `router.navigate`, but as I do not need any id parameter, I want to get previousUrl wthout passing it from list page as parameter.

Comment: There is no direct way. One common workaround is to use RxJS `pairwise` operator. But I doubt it'd help you. I believe you're running into the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Perhaps there is another way of solving it if you could elaborate _why_ it's required rather than asking _how_.

Comment: Thanks but the scenario is clear I think.I just need to get previous url on a Component.

Comment: You still haven't answered the _why_ part of the question. Nevertheless, there is no direct way and a workaround needs to be used.

Comment: I'm trying to help you here. Like I said before perhaps there is another way of solving it without the workarounds.

Comment: I am sure for that. But I would expect at least a suggestion related to `pairwise`

Comment: I already look at many pages including your suggestion.

Comment: Subscribe to `route` with `pairwise()` in App Component -> cache the result using a `ReplaySubject` in a singleton -> use it's value in other components. Attempt this, and the community would be more than happy to aid you in any hurdle that you may come across.